# How to draw a line in the shape of a square with rounded corners?

Tags: android, drawing

I am very glad of your help! I use the following code:

```
Paint mPaintShape = new Paint();
mPaintShape.setStrokeWidth(AppUtill.dp2px(getContext(), 4));
mPaintShape.setColor(mNormalColor);
mPaintShape.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, mSize, mSize);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mPaintShape);
    }
```

And I get the following result. But I want to have rounded outer corners
How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create a style file as given
allround.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#ff6600" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#EAD61C" />
        <corners
            android:radius="7dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ffff00"
            android:endColor="#FEC34D"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#2f6699" />
        <corners
            android:radius="7dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

and apply this style in your layout component as follow-

```
android:background="@drawable/allround"
```

OR YOU can USE>>>>>>>>>>

```
RectF r = new RectF(1,2,3,4);
canvas.drawRoundRect(r, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do this in the method onDraw

Comment: i have added that solution too

Comment: My problem is that I want to get a line in the shape of a square with rounded outer corners. Do you want to invite me to use two squares with complete filling? So that an external had rounded corners and the inside no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/btnpressed">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#6B0000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#6B0000" />
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#794C3F"
                android:endColor="#794C3F"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#794C3F" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `Canvas.drawLine()` and  `Canvas.draw Arc()`. I introduced the offset and set 'mSize' according to the measured Height/ Width to be sure that the desired stroke width is visible on all edges. Modifiying the 'mCornerRadius' will, of course, change the corners.

I used a red Paint with corner radius 8 to get this:

[image]

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // to make sure that the whole shape fits into the View
    // (else some lines may be thinner/ missing)
    mSize = Math.min(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth())*0.8f;

    float offset_top = 4;
    float offset_left = 4;
    float sizeMinusRadius = mSize - mCornerRadius;

    // horizontal lines
    canvas.drawLine(offset_left + mCornerRadius, offset_top, offset_left + sizeMinusRadius, offset_top, mPaintShape);
    canvas.drawLine(offset_left + mCornerRadius, offset_top + mSize, offset_left + sizeMinusRadius, offset_top + mSize, mPaintShape);

    // vertical lines
    canvas.drawLine(offset_left, offset_top + mCornerRadius, offset_left, offset_top + sizeMinusRadius, mPaintShape);
    canvas.drawLine(offset_left + mSize, offset_top + mCornerRadius, offset_left + mSize, offset_top + sizeMinusRadius, mPaintShape);

    // corner bottom left
    RectF rBottomLeft = new RectF(offset_left, 
          offset_top + mSize - 2 * mCornerRadius, offset_left + 2 * mCornerRadius,
          offset_top + mSize);
    canvas.drawArc(rBottomLeft, 90, 90, false, mPaintShape);
    // corner bottom right
    RectF rBottomRight = new RectF(offset_left + mSize - 2 * mCornerRadius,
        offset_top + mSize - 2 * mCornerRadius, offset_left + mSize, offset_top + mSize);
    canvas.drawArc(rBottomRight, 0, 90, false, mPaintShape);
    // corner top left
    RectF rTopLeft = new RectF(offset_left, offset_top, 
                offset_left + 2 * mCornerRadius, offset_top + 2 * mCornerRadius);
    canvas.drawArc(rTopLeft, 180, 90, false, mPaintShape);
    // corner top right
    RectF rTopRight = new RectF(offset_left + mSize - 2 * mCornerRadius, offset_top, 
                            offset_left + mSize, offset_top + 2 * mCornerRadius);
    canvas.drawArc(rTopRight, 270, 90, false, mPaintShape);
}
```